# Filling checkboxes with values from an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have some checkboxes that I am getting the values into an array:

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="daily[]" value="0"></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="daily[]" value="1"></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="daily[]" value="2"></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="daily[]" value="3"></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="daily[]" value="4"></li>
</ul>
```

I am using this function to get the values into the array:

```
var days = $('input[name^='+daily+']:checked').map(function(){
  return parseInt($(this).val(),10);
}).get();
```

This is working well..
But now I want to do the inverse.. To fill an edit form, I want to check the checkboxes when having the array. How could I do that in a good way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate the array - create a selector for the checkbox element - verify the element exists - set the `checked` property:

```
for (var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
    var value = days[i];
    var selector = 'ul li input[value="' + value + '"]')
    var elem = $(selector);
    if (elem) {
        elem.prop("checked", true);
    }
}
```

Or:

```
$('input[name^='+daily+']').prop("checked", function() {
    return days.indexOf(this.value) > -1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like,

```
var arr = ["2","3","4"];
var elems = $('input[name^='+daily+']');
arr.forEach(function(val){
 elems.filter("[value="+ val +"]").prop("checked",true);
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/shnr97Ls/)

***Points to be noted:***

- Try to cache your selector outside the iteration phase, that would
  improve the performance.
- Iterating over all the elements and checking its value against the
  array would cause severe performance drawback when you have 100+
  elements and your array size is 2.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this :

```js
var days = [0, 2, 3];
var $checkboxes = $('input[name^=daily]');

days.forEach(function(day) {
    $checkboxes.get(day).checked = true;
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="daily[]" value="0"></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="daily[]" value="1"></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="daily[]" value="2"></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="daily[]" value="3"></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="daily[]" value="4"></li>
</ul>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lc55148q/1/))